# Devising equation for word problem

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-distributions, geometric-probability

I'm looking to devise an equation for the following problem but can't seem to figure it out with my current knowledge.

A train is going from London to Paris. It stops at 5 stations on the way. At each station it waits 2.5 minutes and it then has a 70% chance of going to the next station or a 30% change of waiting another 5 minutes. If it waits the 5 minutes, after the time is up it again has a 70% of going and 30% chance of staying (potentially infinite times).

Disregarding the time it takes to move between stations, what would be an average travel time for this train to get from London to Paris.

Comment: Try calculating the expected waiting time at one station. The expected wait time at each station will be the sum of each possible wait times multiplied by the probability of that wait time occurring. Then you can multiply this expected wait time by 5 to get the total expected travel time.

Comment: Hmm, there are indeed 5 intermediate stations on the line between London and Paris (Stratford Intl, Ashford Intl, Calais-Fréthun, Lille-Europe and TGV Haute-Picardie), but the through trains don't stop at Stratford or Haute-Picardie. Are you sure you're reading the timetable right?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Don't be silly. Mathematicians don't live in the real world :D

Comment: @gowrath Have a look at my update please!

Comment: @Cellydy Ah that is a much more interesting question. I'll write an answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to calculate the expected wait time at a station. We know that the train waits 2.5 mins at all stations. Let us call the expected time a train waits at a station t. Then we have:
$$
t = 2.5 + 0.3(5 + 0.3(5 + 0.3(5 +\dots)))
$$
Let me explain the above. After waiting the initial 2.5, the train has a 0.3 chance of waiting 5 mins plus the "additional however much it might wait". This "additional however much it might wait" could be exactly 5 mins or theres a 0.3 chance that it might wait another 5 and so on, hence the infinite brackets.

So how do we calculate the above value? Let us call the expected time a train waits above the basic 2.5 minutes $t_e$. Then

$$t_e = 0.3(5 + 0.3(5 + 0.3(5 +\dots)))$$
and so
$$t = 2.5 + t_e $$

Now notice how $t_e$ is contained within itself. That is

$$t_e = 0.3(5 + t_e)$$

and so using this we can solve for $t_e$
$$
\begin{split}
t_e &= 0.3(5 + t_e) \\
t_e &= 1.5 + 0.3t_e \\
0.7t_e &= 1.5 \\
t_e &= \frac{15}{7}
\end{split}
$$

and so the total expected wait time at each station is

$$
 t = 2.5 +  \frac{15}{7} \\
$$

Comment: @Cellydy No worries! If you feel your question has been answered, up vote all inputs you felt were helpful + mark one of the replies as the answer so that this question doesn't remain in the unanswered section.

Answer (score 0):

A short wait lasts $s=2.5$ minutes and occurs with probability $p=0.7$. A long one $l=7.5$ minutes with probability $1-p=0.3$.

The expected waiting time at a station is $sp+(1-p)l$.

---

**Update**:

With the new rule of the game,

$$sp+(1-p)(pd+(1-p)(pd+(1-p)pd+\cdots))$$

The iterated term, let $t$, is such that

$$pd+(1-p)t=t$$ where $d=5$ minutes.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention an important point. It waits 2.5 minutes and then it has a 70% change of going and a 30% chance of staying. If it stays for the 5 minutes, then again after 5 minutes, it has 70% of going and 30% chance of staying (and that to infinity).

Comment: I'm a little unclear as to how I can calculate the expected waiting time at a station from your answer. I hope you can bless me with a little more help.

Comment: I believe the first term in your updated version should be $s$ not $sp$. That is: $$s+(1-p)(pd+(1-p)(pd+(1-p)pd+\cdots))$$.